# How to change the year of a msg email outlook 2013 with minimum software (notepad ++...)

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2013

I have an email that I regularly feed with data.  I use the "modify" feature to bring the new updates in this email.  The problem is that I must send it to myself to update the date in order to view it in first in the display.  I'd like to change the reception date to 2099 to display it always at the top of the display list.

I tried to convert it to plain text, HTML... and to import it, but outlook saves it and the date relates to the saving date.
Is there a way to change this date rather than sending it to myself everytime I update it?

Comment: Why do you need to modify that e-mail? Why it need to be an e-mail at all? Why it need to be in your inbox and not in your drafts folder? What is "modify feature"? ...

Comment: Is there any reason you don't keep it as a file or as it has been pointed out as a draft? Alternatively create a folder in your Inbox and just put that mail in it?

Comment: All the solutions you propose are good but not enough convenient for my job.
I just try to limit the actions in outlook and it'll be more convenient to see this email always on the top during that the received ones display just below.
It's quite simple.
I perfectly know that I can use filters, seraches, draft, categories...
Who cares, I just would want to see this email always in first.
If there's a means...

Comment: The "modify" feature is available when the email is open, not only displayed in the email list, and it is possible to modify the content and the object by clicking on the "modify the message" button under the "actions" menu in "Move" group.
It's very usefull when your customers aren't rigorous enough when they reply to an email with the object of another one.
But this feature doesn't allow editing of date or any in the header.

Comment: @pipout64 - Edit your question then delete your comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the free [Set Field Value](https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookHeadersSet) utility for that. After installing (with Outlook add-in!), right-click the required message and use the context menu to run the "Set Field Value" utility. Set **MessageDeliveryTime** as a "Field name" and **2099/01/01** as a "Value to set". Click Run and that's pretty much of it. Please note that I recommend the mentioned tool because I'm one of the developers.